# Stopped nginx container but it still shows up on browser

Tags: docker, nginx

I made a docker container published to port '3000', When going to the web browser's "localhost:3000" it shows that the nginx is working but after i stopped and killed the container it is still showing up in my browser even thou it shouldn't
Note: I deleted all cache, Cookies, Browser history of my browser but still it shows up

Comment: What is the output of `docker ps`  and how exactly did you shut down the container in question?

Comment: i did the following
docker container stop 'container name'
and then killed it. 'Docker ps -a' shows no container running.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Linux as your host OS?

Docker container processes are Linux processes.

One, general-purpose mechanism to determine which port is being used by which process is, e.g.:

```sh
ss --tcp --listening --processes | grep 3000
```

better:

```sh
ss --tcp --listening --processes '( src = :3000 )'
```

**NB** You may need to run the above as `sudo` to get processes running under root.

For me to repro your issue:

```sh
docker run --interactive --tty --publish=3000:80 nginx
```

Then:

```sh
sudo ss --tcp --listening --processes '( src = :3000 )'
State    Local    Peer
LISTEN   *:3000   *:*             users:(("docker-proxy",pid=21308,fd=4))

ps aux | grep 21308
21308 docker-proxy -proto tcp -host-ip 0.0.0.0 -host-port 3000 -container-port 80
```

**NB** The above is edited heavily to convey the point.

Hopefully you can see that the process `21308` is the one on port `:3000`

It's a process corresponding to `docker-proxy` and, per the process, it maps the host's `:3000` to a container port `:80`.

Because you know (expect) the process to be a docker container, you can:

```sh
docker container ls --all
CONTAINER ID  IMAGE  COMMAND                  PORTS
197ee6d0ab00  nginx  "nginx -g 'daemon of…"   0.0.0.0:3000->80/tcp
```

You can see that there's a port mapping (in use) from the host's `:3000`.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem but found a different solution. If you clear the cache for nginx it should fix this:

```
sudo rm -rf /var/cache/nginx/*
```